# How can I merge the 3 AMLsim example datasets to 1 csv file so that ML model can be trained?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, merge

Does anyone know how I could merge the Alert, Transaction and Account datasets from the AML simulator?

For data see: https://github.com/IBM/AMLSim/wiki/Download-Example-Data-Set#1k-100k-1k-accounts-100k-transactions

The following code gives a Dtype error due to the inconsistencies between the datasets.

```
os.chdir("/path")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv2.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

I don't understand how these files could be compiled into 1 csv in order to train my machine learning models, since I am not completely sure they have a common ground.

Comment: The 3 files can be seen as 3 related tables in a relational database. That means that at pandas level, you should use `merge` and not `concat` to combine them. But you should first look at their structure, understand it, and define what you want in the compiled file (in database words it would be *build a select query*).